# How to send ajax at a single entry point

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, datatables

There was such question, it is necessary to send ajax at loading view, but because of that the uniform point of an input is created, can not specify the address.

Some code: .htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

The simplest router is written, which scans $ _SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'] and cuts it into parts. Sample code is too long publication, but I'll try. /app/core/route.php:

```
<?php
class Route
{
    static function start() 
    {
        $controller_name = 'Main';
        $action_name = 'index';
        $params = null;
        $routes = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        if (!empty($routes[2])){ #
            $controller_name = $routes[2];
        }
        if (!empty($routes[3])){ 
            $action_name = $routes[3];
        }
        if (!empty(array_slice($routes, 4))) { 
            $params = array_slice($routes, 4);
        }

        $model_name = 'Model_' . $controller_name; 
        $controller_name = 'Controller_' . $controller_name; 
        $action_name = 'action_' . $action_name; 
        $model_file = mb_strtolower($model_name) . '.php'; 
        $model_path = "app/models/" . $model_file; 
        if (file_exists($model_path)) {
            include "app/models/" . $model_file;
        }
        $controller_file = mb_strtolower($controller_name) . ".php"; 
        $controller_path = "app/controller/" . $controller_file; 
        if (file_exists($controller_path)) { 
            include "app/controller/" . $controller_file;
        } else { 
            Route::ErrorPage404();
        }
        if (!class_exists($controller_name)) { 
            Route::ErrorPage404();
        } else { 
            $controller = new $controller_name;
            $action = $action_name;
            if (method_exists($controller, $action)) {
                if ($controller_name != 'Controller_auth') {
                    if ($controller->check_login_status()) {
                        if ($params) {
                            $controller->$action($params);
                        } else {
                            $controller->$action();
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    if ($params) {
                        $controller->$action($params);
                    } else {
                        $controller->$action();
                    }
                }

            } else {
                Route::ErrorPage404();
            }
        }


    }   

    function ErrorPage404()
    {
        $host = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/super_crm/';
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
        header("Status: 404 Not Found");
        header('Location:' . $host . '404'); #редирект на контроллер 404
    }

    function AuthPage()
    {
        $host = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/super_crm/main';
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
        header("Status: 404 Not Found");
        header('Location:' . $host); 
    }

}
```

The processing and result is output in the controller app / controller / controller_join.php:

```
function action_test() { 
        $ajax_test = $this->model->ajax_test();
        $ajax_json = json_encode($ajax_test, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        //header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF8');
        return ($ajax_json);
}
```

Also tried to derive this way:

```
function action_test() { 
        $ajax_test = $this->model->ajax_test();

        $this->view->generate('join/_search_result.php', 'join/_search_result.php',
                                array(
                                        'title' => 'Заявки на подключения!',
                                        'objects' => $ajax_test
                                     )
                              );
    }
```

as a result, when you go directly to the page, the join / test produces the correct json (the cast in json is made in the view)

AJAX itself needs to be sent in this request and the essence of the question is how to correctly specify the address to which the request will be sent (if you specify / join / test (get error 404), I expect that it is necessary to correct .htaccess, so that it would be possible to direct to the file send requests mine index.php while weakly familiar with this, I want to understand if there are solutions easier, I will be very grateful.

Jquery itself:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#main_table').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "join/test"
    } );
} );
```